# Is there a way to store a MemoryHandle exclusively in unmanaged memory?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a method which takes in a `Memory<T>` object. I want to pin it, and store a pointer to it *exclusively* in unmanaged memory. I know I can get this pinned pointer by using `memory.Pin()` to create a `MemoryHandle` and then grabbing `memoryHandle.Pointer`. However, because I only want to store this in unmanaged memory I need to ensure that the managed object the memory handle points somewhere into is not collected until I am done with it. Is there a way I can store the `MemoryHandle` in unmanaged memory without the underlying object being collected, than free it at a later time?

I know that in theory this can be done by storing a `GCHandle` alongside my pointer than disposing it when I'm done. The problem is I don't see any way to retrieve a `GCHandle` from the `Memory` or `MemoryHandle` objects, even though I'm pretty sure at least the memory handle contains a GC handle internally. So, if there where a way to get a `GCHandle` from the `MemoryHandle` that would be a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the whole `MemoryHandle` using `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and reverse?

Comment: @Charlieface Because of the reason `MemoryHandle` is not able to be unmanaged to begin with- it could contain an instance of `IPinnable` instead of a `GCHandle`. In this case, you would have to create a GCHandle to the `IPinnable` else it might get collected, but as far as I can tell the `IPinnable` is not exposed anywhere.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I don't think the `IPinnable` is a concern unless it's set to something that's not marshalable.

Comment: @Charlieface Correct me if I'm wrong, but weather or not it can be marshaled doesn't matter. Because it's an interface and there is no generic parameter, itn't is boxed no matter what? That would mean it's a managed reference which needs a GCHandle.

Comment: True it could cause problems if `IPinnable` is used, not because of boxing, but because you won't get back the same reference. But it seems in this case no `IPinnable` is used https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/08903c00860939af0d291eb3f3c037a18d9820f6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Memory.cs#L418

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure what you mean 'in this case no `IPinnable` is used', doesn't [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/08903c00860939af0d291eb3f3c037a18d9820f6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Memory.cs#L426) create a `MemoryHandle` from a `MemoryManager<T>` which is the `IPinnable`?

Comment: That is specific handling for the case when the `Memory<T>` is constructed from a `MemoryManager<T>`. If it's just a bare array then that is handled by the `else if above that, as linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. It is a simple wrapper around a `GCHandle`. There is a method which creates the handle from a `MemoryHandle` in a safe way which avoids object or `GCHandle` allocations in the vast majority of cases. It is important that you do not dispose the `MemoryHandle` you created the `UnmanagedMemoryHandle` from.

```
public unsafe readonly struct UnmanagedMemoryHandle : IDisposable {

    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/MemoryHandle.cs
    private struct ExposedMemoryHandle {
        public void* Pointer;
        public GCHandle Handle;
        public IPinnable? Pinnable;
    }

    public static UnmanagedMemoryHandle FromMemoryHandle(MemoryHandle memoryHandle) {
        return FromMemoryHandle(ref memoryHandle);
    }

    public static UnmanagedMemoryHandle FromMemoryHandle(ref MemoryHandle memoryHandle) {
        ref ExposedMemoryHandle exposedMemoryHandle = ref Unsafe.As<MemoryHandle, ExposedMemoryHandle>(ref memoryHandle);

        bool hasHandle = exposedMemoryHandle.Handle.IsAllocated;
        bool hasPinnable = exposedMemoryHandle.Pinnable != null;

        GCHandle handle;

        if (hasHandle && !hasPinnable) {
            if (exposedMemoryHandle.Handle.Target is not IPinnable) {
                // If we only have a handle, we just store that handle
                handle = exposedMemoryHandle.Handle;
            } else {
                // Later, we check if the handle is an instance to IPinnable to see if we need to unpin it.
                //  That's a problem in the case the the Handle just happens to be an IPinnable. In this case
                //  we wrap our handle in a type that is not IPinnable
                handle = GCHandle.Alloc(new DoubleMemoryHandle(exposedMemoryHandle.Handle, null));
            }
        } else if (hasPinnable && !hasHandle) {
            // If we only have a pinnable, we store a handle to that pinnable
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(exposedMemoryHandle.Pinnable);
        } else if (hasHandle && hasPinnable) {
            // If we have both, store a handle to an object containing the handle and pinnable
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(new DoubleMemoryHandle(exposedMemoryHandle.Handle, exposedMemoryHandle.Pinnable));
        } else {
            // If we have neither, we don't need to store anything
            handle = default;
        }

        return new UnmanagedMemoryHandle(handle);
    }

    private record DoubleMemoryHandle(GCHandle Handle, IPinnable? Pinnable);

    public readonly GCHandle Handle;

    private UnmanagedMemoryHandle(GCHandle handle) {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (!Handle.IsAllocated) return;

        object? target = Handle.Target;

        if (target is IPinnable pinnable) {
            pinnable.Unpin();
        } else if (target is DoubleMemoryHandle doubleMemoryHandle) {
            doubleMemoryHandle.Handle.Free();
            doubleMemoryHandle.Pinnable?.Unpin();
        }

        Handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just marshal it using `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

```cs
MemoryHandle memoryHandle = data.Pin();
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(meoryHandle, YourPointerHere, false);
}
catch
{
    memoryHandle.Dispose();  // dispose the handle in case of failure only
    throw;
}
```

```cs
MemoryHandle memoryHandle = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MemoryHandle>(YourPointerHere, false);

// do stuff

memoryHandle.Dispose();
Marshal.StructureToPtr(default(MemoryHandle), YourPtrHere);  // wipe struct to prevent reuse
```

Do note that if the `Memory<T>` is backed by a `MemoryManager` then an `IPinnable` will be used in the handle, which means it probably won't be marshalled correctly.

Comment: +1 Because this answer works in most cases (when the `Memory<T>` is created from an array) and is fast-ish, but I think it's very important to add that this has the potential to cause some nasty crashes in the case that the memory is backed by some other mechanism (using a `MemoryManager<T>`). To me, this is not a true solution because it only covers a subset of `MemoryHandle`s.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the thought that this can probably be done by storing a `GCHandle` to the `MemoryHandle` rather than to the underlying object itself. Something like:

```
MemoryHandle memoryHandle = data.Pin();

void* pMemory = memoryHandle.Pointer;
GCHandle memoryHandleHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(memoryHandle);

// Store pMemory and memoryHandleHandle in unmanaged memory...
// Then to dispose:

((MemoryHandle) memoryHandleHandle.Target!).Dispose();
memoryHandleHandle.Free();
```

I think this would work and is safe, but feels very silly, fragile and ugly compared to the theoretical solution of just getting the `GCHandle` to the underlying object instead. The biggest real disadvantage is that this comes at the cost of a boxing allocation (boxing the MemoryHandle), something I would prefer to avoid given this is a very hot code path.